# If $M$ is a nonorientable $3$-manifold, why is $H_1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ infinite?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M$ be a compact connected $3$-manifold with boundary $\partial M$. If $M$ is nonorientable and $\partial M$ is empty, then how do I see that $H_1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is infinite?

Comment: You need $\partial M$ non empty, otherwise it is false. The proof is explain in every textbook on 3-manifolds, Hempel, Jaco for instance. just write the exact sequence relating of homology of the manifold, homology relative to the boundary and homology of the boundary, and look at the term conatining $H_1$

Comment: @Thomas can you provide a counter example?

Comment: These object are studied as "homology spheres"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Constructions_and_examples

Comment: @Thomas: Homology spheres are orientable.

Comment: @EricWofsey, sorry I did not read the question correctly...

Comment: Counter example for non-orientable with boundary is $\mathbb RP^2\times I$. Its fundamental group is $\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every odd-dimensional manifold has vanishing Euler characteristic, so $$0 = \chi(M) = b_0 - b_1 + b_2 - b_3.$$We have $b_0 = 1$, and $b_3 = 0$ since $M$ is nonorientable. Hence, $b_1 > 0$ and thus $H_1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is infinite.